# CSS Flexbox text is out of div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like that the elements `nav`, `#left` and `#right` have always the same height and that the text inside is always in the element and not outside.

```
<body>
    <header>
        text
    </header>
    <main>
    <nav>
        some links
    </nav>
    <section id="content">
       <div id="headline">
            Text
        </div>
         <div id="contentText">
            <div id="left">
                text
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
 header { 
        display: flex;
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
    }
    #logo{
        width: 15%;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #messages{
        width: 5%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #notifications{
        width: 5%;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #search{
        width: 5%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #searchArea{
        flex: 1;
        background: red;
    }
    #profileArea{
        width: 10%;
        background: yellow;
    }
    #options{
        width: 3%;
        background: red;
    }
    main{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 60px);
        min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
        background: blue;
    }
    nav { 
        width: 15%;
        min-height: 100%;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .link{
        width: 100%;
        height: 3%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #content{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 85%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        background: grey;
    }
    #headline{
        width: 100%;
        height: 5%;
        background-color: pink;
    }
    #contentText{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 95%;
        background: red;
    }
    #left{
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        background: red;
    }
    #right{
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        background: yellow;
    }
```

For further infomation have a look at my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u891bahd/)

Comment: No code in the question = bad bad bad! :) Please add in some HTML/CSS so it is possible to replicate the issue without going to jsfiddle (though the fiddle is a plus)

Comment: Just a hint, if you want to have a bigger spacing between line of text please avoid using tons of <br> and set instead the CSS property `line-height: 3.0;` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove #contentText height it should be

```
#contentText{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;

    background: red;
}
main{
    display: flex;
    background: blue;
}
nav { 
    width: 15%;
    background-color: green;   
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: yeah, but now I got a little space under both div's and the nav still not getting the same size :/

Comment: ad the nav css too check

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove height #contentText

```
#contentText{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
  /*height: 95%;*/
    background: red;
}
```